# Ninja Forms поменять содержимое value скрытого input

Tags: wordpress

Пытаюсь поменять содержимое value скрытого input, но почему то не меняется, может что-то не так делаю?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var fieldID = 38;
    var newValue = '<?php echo strip_tags($expertiza); ?>';
    $('#nf-field-' + fieldID).val(newValue).trigger('change');
});         
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение нашли в этот же день.

```
$( ".p-btn a" ).click(function() {
    var subj = $( this ).parent("p").prevAll('.process-exp-head:first').find(".process-exp-e").text();

    $("#nf-field-38").val($.trim(subj));
    console.log($("#nf-field-38").val());                                           
});
```